# Can't see node after joining it to cluster - "getsockopt: connection refused"

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am new in Kubernetes.

I have two nodes:

- Master
- Worker

I installed Kubernetes on both of them and on the muster I ran the `kubeadm init...` command in the Master node and received the command to join a new worker to the cluster:

```
sudo kubeadm join --token 61a503.3bdf2341a37a2732 192.168.190.159:6443 --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:ef66d8b7284af9e80f18767af39b5f164e00fd7fe714d3092e8ff682f07076da
```

I ran the above command inside the Worker node and it seems that it succeed:
[image]

This is the output:

```
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks.
    [WARNING FileExisting-crictl]: crictl not found in system path
[discovery] Trying to connect to API Server "192.168.190.159:6443"
[discovery] Created cluster-info discovery client, requesting info from "https://192.168.190.159:6443"
[discovery] Requesting info from "https://192.168.190.159:6443" again to validate TLS against the pinned public key
[discovery] Cluster info signature and contents are valid and TLS certificate validates against pinned roots, will use API Server "192.168.190.159:6443"
[discovery] Successfully established connection with API Server "192.168.190.159:6443"

This node has joined the cluster:
* Certificate signing request was sent to master and a response
  was received.
* The Kubelet was informed of the new secure connection details.

Run 'kubectl get nodes' on the master to see this node join the cluster.
```

But when I go to the Master and run:

```
kubectl get nodes
```

I see only the master:

```
master@osboxes:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME      STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
osboxes   Ready     master    4h        v1.9.1
```

Docker version on both nodes:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.13.1
 API version:  1.26
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   092cba3
 Built:        Thu Nov  2 20:40:23 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.13.1
 API version:  1.26 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.6.2
 Git commit:   092cba3
 Built:        Thu Nov  2 20:40:23 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

How can I find what is the problem?
Any idea what can it be ?
By the way, I tried the same thing on two nodes in AWS and it worked fine.

**EDIT (15.5.2018): Logs**
These are the logs from the kubelet daemon from the Worker node, I exported it with `sudo journalctl -u kubelet > logs.txt`

```
May 15 06:39:05 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:05.113840   12160 kubelet_node_status.go:375] Unable to update node status: update node status exceeds retry count
May 15 06:39:06 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:06.060871   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:465: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:06 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:06.072458   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:06 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:06.075082   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:474: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:07 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:07.064412   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:465: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:07 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:07.082627   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:474: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:07 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:07.084203   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:08 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:08.084848   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:474: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:08 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:08.085296   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:465: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:08 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:08.086186   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:09 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:09.091850   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:09 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:09.092907   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:465: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:09 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:09.093494   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:474: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:10 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:10.094472   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:10 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:10.097289   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:465: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:10 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:10.098355   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:474: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:11 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:11.101260   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:465: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:11 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:11.102788   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:474: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:11 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:11.103772   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:12 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:12.109494   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:474: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:12 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:12.126419   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:465: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:12 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:12.127858   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:13 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:13.128797   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:474: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:13 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:13.130811   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:465: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:13 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:13.132159   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:14 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:14.132703   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:474: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:14 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:14.133885   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:465: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:14 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:14.134534   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:15 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:15.123979   12160 kubelet_node_status.go:383] Error updating node status, will retry: error getting node "osboxes": Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/nodes/osboxes?resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:15 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:15.126886   12160 kubelet_node_status.go:383] Error updating node status, will retry: error getting node "osboxes": Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/nodes/osboxes: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:15 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:15.128832   12160 kubelet_node_status.go:383] Error updating node status, will retry: error getting node "osboxes": Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/nodes/osboxes: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:15 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:15.132161   12160 kubelet_node_status.go:383] Error updating node status, will retry: error getting node "osboxes": Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/nodes/osboxes: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:15 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:15.134043   12160 kubelet_node_status.go:383] Error updating node status, will retry: error getting node "osboxes": Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/nodes/osboxes: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:15 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:15.134746   12160 kubelet_node_status.go:375] Unable to update node status: update node status exceeds retry count
May 15 06:39:15 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:15.142404   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:474: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:15 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:15.143773   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:15 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:15.144730   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:465: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:16 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:16.146062   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:16 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:16.147948   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:474: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:16 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:16.148963   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:465: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:17 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:17.153690   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:17 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:17.169648   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:465: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:17 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:17.170775   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:474: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:18 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:18.171909   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:18 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:18.174020   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:474: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:18 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:18.175013   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:465: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:19 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:19.178296   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:19 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:19.182903   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:465: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:19 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:19.184147   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:474: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:20 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:20.183063   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:20 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:20.198007   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:465: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:20 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:20.199996   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:474: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:21 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:21.186122   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/config/apiserver.go:47: Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:21 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:21.203974   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:474: Failed to list *v1.Node: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dosboxes&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
May 15 06:39:21 osboxes kubelet[12160]: E0515 06:39:21.207920   12160 reflector.go:205] k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:465: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://192.168.190.159:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
```

**Logs from Kubelet:**

```
worker2@osboxes:~$ sudo kubelet
I0515 11:22:38.938557   33604 feature_gate.go:220] feature gates: &{{} map[]}
I0515 11:22:38.938712   33604 controller.go:114] kubelet config controller: starting controller
I0515 11:22:38.938757   33604 controller.go:118] kubelet config controller: validating combination of defaults and flags
W0515 11:22:38.949230   33604 cni.go:171] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
I0515 11:22:38.987488   33604 server.go:182] Version: v1.9.1
I0515 11:22:38.987524   33604 feature_gate.go:220] feature gates: &{{} map[]}
I0515 11:22:38.987620   33604 plugins.go:101] No cloud provider specified.
W0515 11:22:38.987656   33604 server.go:328] standalone mode, no API client
W0515 11:22:39.028891   33604 server.go:236] No api server defined - no events will be sent to API server.
I0515 11:22:39.028997   33604 server.go:428] --cgroups-per-qos enabled, but --cgroup-root was not specified.  defaulting to /
I0515 11:22:39.029367   33604 container_manager_linux.go:242] container manager verified user specified cgroup-root exists: /
I0515 11:22:39.029459   33604 container_manager_linux.go:247] Creating Container Manager object based on Node Config: {RuntimeCgroupsName: SystemCgroupsName: KubeletCgroupsName: ContainerRuntime:docker CgroupsPerQOS:true CgroupRoot:/ CgroupDriver:cgroupfs KubeletRootDir:/var/lib/kubelet ProtectKernelDefaults:false NodeAllocatableConfig:{KubeReservedCgroupName: SystemReservedCgroupName: EnforceNodeAllocatable:map[pods:{}] KubeReserved:map[] SystemReserved:map[] HardEvictionThresholds:[{Signal:memory.available Operator:LessThan Value:{Quantity:100Mi Percentage:0} GracePeriod:0s MinReclaim:<nil>} {Signal:nodefs.available Operator:LessThan Value:{Quantity:<nil> Percentage:0.1} GracePeriod:0s MinReclaim:<nil>} {Signal:nodefs.inodesFree Operator:LessThan Value:{Quantity:<nil> Percentage:0.05} GracePeriod:0s MinReclaim:<nil>} {Signal:imagefs.available Operator:LessThan Value:{Quantity:<nil> Percentage:0.15} GracePeriod:0s MinReclaim:<nil>}]} ExperimentalQOSReserved:map[] ExperimentalCPUManagerPolicy:none ExperimentalCPUManagerReconcilePeriod:10s}
I0515 11:22:39.029627   33604 container_manager_linux.go:266] Creating device plugin manager: false
W0515 11:22:39.032405   33604 kubelet_network.go:139] Hairpin mode set to "promiscuous-bridge" but kubenet is not enabled, falling back to "hairpin-veth"
I0515 11:22:39.032456   33604 kubelet.go:571] Hairpin mode set to "hairpin-veth"
I0515 11:22:39.034512   33604 client.go:80] Connecting to docker on unix:///var/run/docker.sock
I0515 11:22:39.034568   33604 client.go:109] Start docker client with request timeout=2m0s
W0515 11:22:39.042224   33604 cni.go:171] Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d
I0515 11:22:39.052530   33604 docker_service.go:232] Docker cri networking managed by kubernetes.io/no-op
I0515 11:22:39.075356   33604 docker_service.go:237] Docker Info: &{ID:N4M2:L4UZ:CZTV:LQHL:KAFZ:EB2Z:ZCF2:ED6G:KRR4:AI6X:KFQH:BTAH Containers:2 ContainersRunning:2 ContainersPaused:0 ContainersStopped:0 Images:7 Driver:aufs DriverStatus:[[Root Dir /var/lib/docker/aufs] [Backing Filesystem extfs] [Dirs 25] [Dirperm1 Supported true]] SystemStatus:[] Plugins:{Volume:[local] Network:[bridge host macvlan null overlay] Authorization:[] Log:[]} MemoryLimit:true SwapLimit:false KernelMemory:true CPUCfsPeriod:true CPUCfsQuota:true CPUShares:true CPUSet:true IPv4Forwarding:true BridgeNfIptables:true BridgeNfIP6tables:true Debug:false NFd:29 OomKillDisable:true NGoroutines:34 SystemTime:2018-05-15T11:22:39.055044415-04:00 LoggingDriver:json-file CgroupDriver:cgroupfs NEventsListener:0 KernelVersion:4.13.0-36-generic OperatingSystem:Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS OSType:linux Architecture:x86_64 IndexServerAddress:https://index.docker.io/v1/ RegistryConfig:0xc4206ae690 NCPU:1 MemTotal:2066481152 GenericResources:[] DockerRootDir:/var/lib/docker HTTPProxy: HTTPSProxy: NoProxy: Name:osboxes Labels:[] ExperimentalBuild:false ServerVersion:1.13.1 ClusterStore: ClusterAdvertise: Runtimes:map[runc:{Path:runc Args:[]}] DefaultRuntime:runc Swarm:{NodeID: NodeAddr: LocalNodeState:inactive ControlAvailable:false Error: RemoteManagers:[] Nodes:0 Managers:0 Cluster:0xc420690500} LiveRestoreEnabled:false Isolation: InitBinary:docker-init ContainerdCommit:{ID: Expected:aa8187dbd3b7ad67d8e5e3a15115d3eef43a7ed1} RuncCommit:{ID:N/A Expected:9df8b306d01f59d3a8029be411de015b7304dd8f} InitCommit:{ID:N/A Expected:949e6facb77383876aeff8a6944dde66b3089574} SecurityOptions:[name=apparmor name=seccomp,profile=default]}
I0515 11:22:39.075476   33604 docker_service.go:250] Setting cgroupDriver to cgroupfs
I0515 11:22:39.103735   33604 remote_runtime.go:43] Connecting to runtime service unix:///var/run/dockershim.sock
I0515 11:22:39.105235   33604 kuberuntime_manager.go:186] Container runtime docker initialized, version: 1.13.1, apiVersion: 1.26.0
I0515 11:22:39.114094   33604 server.go:755] Started kubelet
E0515 11:22:39.114169   33604 server.go:511] Starting health server failed: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:10248: bind: address already in use
E0515 11:22:39.114305   33604 kubelet.go:1275] Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data for container /
W0515 11:22:39.114329   33604 kubelet.go:1359] No api server defined - no node status update will be sent.
I0515 11:22:39.114672   33604 kubelet_node_status.go:273] Setting node annotation to enable volume controller attach/detach
I0515 11:22:39.115490   33604 server.go:129] Starting to listen on 0.0.0.0:10250
I0515 11:22:39.117147   33604 server.go:299] Adding debug handlers to kubelet server.
F0515 11:22:39.119054   33604 server.go:141] listen tcp 0.0.0.0:10250: bind: address already in use
```

Comment: Hi, can you check if kubelet is running on worker node ?

Comment: When I run `worker2@osboxes:~$ kubelet` I received: `I0515 04:13:14.490848   36357 feature_gate.go:220] feature gates: &{{} map[]}
I0515 04:13:14.491154   36357 controller.go:114] kubelet config controller: starting controller
I0515 04:13:14.491288   36357 controller.go:118] kubelet config controller: validating combination of defaults and flags
error: error reading /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.key, certificate and key must be supplied as a pair`

But this error also appear in a working cluster in my AWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem was that both nodes (Master and Worker) had the same hostname :).
I noticed it after I ran `kubectl describe node` and in the `Addresses` field I saw the IP address of the worker with the same `Hostname` of the master:

```
Addresses:
  InternalIP:  192.168.190.162
  Hostname:    worker2node
```

I run `sudo kubeadm reset` on both Master and Worker.
On Master:

```
sudo swapoff -a
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.190.159 
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
kubectl apply -f kube-flannel.yml
```

On Worker:
Changed the hostname:

```
hostnamectl set-hostname worker2node
sudo vi /etc/hosts # (edit this file with the new name for 127.0.1.1)
```

Restart the worker and join it again.
I checked and now it was added.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  error reading /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.key, certificate and key must be supplied as a pair
> ```

Usually, this is a permission issue. Check permissions of the certificate file, it should be readable for Kubelet user.

If it does not help you - please share the Kubelet logs, namely the logs of the daemon, do not start it manually in the console.

Based on the update of the question:

```
192.168.190.159:6443: getsockopt: connection refused
```

It means that `Kubelet` on the node cannot connect to the master. Check the network connection between your node and the master. The node should be able to connect to https://192.168.190.159:6443, which is your API server endpoint.

Comment: I checked the permissions (run `ls -ll` in `/var/lib/kubelet/pki/`) but it seems they have read permissions: `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1103 May 14 07:22 kubelet.crt
-rw------- 1 root root 1679 May 14 07:22 kubelet.key
`

Comment: I am not sure how to do it :/. I am searching, I saw some command `kubectl logs --since=10000h` but it want me to give a container name.

Comment: Kubelet works as a daemon (service) on your node. Try to google of how to get a logs of service in your Linux.

Comment: I updated my answer it part of the logs. I used `sudo journalctl -u kubelet > logs.txt` to do it. It seems that the connection is refused.

Comment: I updated the answer. Actually `kubectl` use the same address to connect to the API, so if `kubectl` works, that is not an API server problem.

Comment: I ran `curl -k https://192.168.190.159:6443` and it writes me: `{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    
  },
  "code": 403
`

Comment: Did you run it on the node with Kubelet? And in the same time Kubelet still cannot start?

Comment: Yes, I ran it on the same node with Kubelet. I am not sure if the Kubelet is running. Btw, I ran on the master `master@osboxes:~$ kubectl get all --namespace=kube-system` and this is the output: 
`NAME                           READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/etcd-osboxes               0/1       Pending   0          3s
pod/kube-dns-6f4fd4bdf-r9lq4   3/3       Running   0          1d
pod/kube-flannel-ds-lqtq8      1/1       Running   0          1d
pod/kube-proxy-6hkcm           1/1       Running   0          1d
pod/kube-scheduler-osboxes     0/1       Pending   0          3s`

Comment: I tried to reset Kubernetes. I ran in the Master and in the Worker `sudo kubeadm reset` and initialize the master and join the worker again and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I updated my answer with logs from `sudo kubelet`. I forgot to use the `sudo`. But I don't see any problem there.